# mysql два запроса в один ряд

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, база-данных

я хачу сделать два запроса в один ряд я реализовал это так: (я дублировал этот файл вписывал туда нужные файлы и делал include_once и с первым файлом и с вторым но там тоже ошибки(И у меня файлы берутся с разных таблиц: stuck, tovar));

```
<?php
include_once 'database.php';
$sucess = "";

if(isset($_POST['save']))
{    
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $product  = $_POST['product'];
    $price  = $_POST['price'];
    $email      = $_POST['email'];
    $uid = $_POST['uid'];

    $sql        = "INSERT INTO tovar (name,product,price,email)
    VALUES ('$name','$product','$price','$email')" && "UPDATE stuck SET sht = (sht - 1)
      WHERE id='$uid'";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
    {
        $sucess = "Insert has been successfully.!";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "
    " . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

А это код ошибки

```
Error: 1 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте это:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tovar (name,product,price,email) VALUES ('$name','$product','$price','$email'); UPDATE stuck SET sht = (sht- 1) WHERE id='$uid'"; 

if(mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql)) { 
    $sucess = "Insert has beensuccessfully.!";
}
```